# app_store_subscription_* events are not exported to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play, firebase-analytics

There are recently added Firebase Analytics Events automatically reported: `app_store_subscription_cancel`/`app_store_subscription_convert`/`app_store_subscription_renew` (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en).

None of them are exported to linked BigQuery DB. Other events are exported well.

Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Was digging with those events in Google Analytics. They do not have any properties (user_id, country, device, ...) also

Answer (score 2):

Got response from the Firebase support. These events are intentionally restricted from being exported to BigQuery due privacy concerns